# Rellenar automáticamente un input al cambiar un select

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla *Pagos*, la cual tiene 3 campos (id, rubro, monto) con la siguiente consulta, con la cual lleno un *combobox* con todos los rubros, ahora deseo hacer que cada vez que seleccione un rubro, el monto se rellene automáticamente en un *input* que tengo en el formulario.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="Old">Tipo de pago* </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select  class="form-control" id="pagos" name="pagos" >
        <option value="" >Selecciona pago</option>
        <?php
            $sql = "select id, rubro, monto from pagos";
            $q = $conn->query($sql);
            
            while($r = $q->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$r['id'].'"  '.(($pagos==$r['id'])?'selected="selected"':'').'>'.$r['rubro'].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos. Particularmente cual es el error, resultado erroneo (que obtiene y que esperas)... ¿que ocurre? Incluye el código que falta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#test").change(() => $("#total").val($( "#test option:selected" ).text()))
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="test" id="test">
<option value="1">100</value>
<option value="2">200</value>
<option value="2">300</value>
</select>

Total: <input id="total" name="total" value="100" />
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Saludos @RicardoAntonioRafaelRivas, no es recomendable crear otro usuario y aceptar o puntuar tus propias preguntas, ya que estarías incurriendo en hacer crecer en puntos a tu mismo usuario de manera ilícita, lo más correcto en este caso seria responder a tu pregunta pero con el mismo usuario con la que preguntaste ;)

Answer (score 1):

Primero decir que si el option está dentro de un form. Se te enviará el valor que haya dentro de `value` del campo seleccionado.

Puedes jugar con hacer un id compuesto como `$id-$rubro` para recuperar eso en PHP cuando se envíe el formulario.

Dicho esto, si necesitas llenar el input para añadir otro tipo de lógica lo que necesitas es usar Javascript, con `JQuery` sería de esta forma:

```js
$("#test").change(() => $("#total").val($( "#test option:selected" ).text()))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="test" id="test">
<option value="1">100</value>
<option value="2">200</value>
<option value="2">300</value>
</select>

Total: <input id="total" name="total" value="100" />
```

Comment: Pero como lo aplicaría para extraer la información desde un campo de una tabla

Comment: por tu ejemplo los rubros están en un option y quieres llenar un input cuando se selecciona el option. Te he dado un ejemplo donde al seleccionar un option se rellena el input con el valor. No tengo claro que no cubre la respuesta.